# How to store and retrieve ASCII text in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, ascii-art

In my iPhone app, i have a requirement for the ASCII art character to be stored in database and displayed.

How should I store and retrieve the ASCII art character in my iphone app?

What should be done?

Please Help and Suggest.

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks!!

ASCII art character are the charaters made from the characters like punctuation symbols and symbols like *,#, etc.

Comment: How large is your dataset? Do you plan on storing anything other than ASCII text?

Comment: No nothing other than the alphabet and its ASCII Text.

Comment: What does this have to do with ASCII art?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use sqlite, it is very easy. Read this tutorial.

http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: How will it store the ASCII art into Sqlite? I want that it is stored along with all formatting

Comment: Save it as string will not losing any formatting information, all need is to replay it right.

Comment: We tried saving in Sqlite but it stores the whole ASCII art in single line and thus multiline ASCII art looses its original formatting.What can be done?